# Graceful shutdown of IHostedService

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core, iis-7.5

I am trying to develop a simple API in .NET Core that allows asynchronous processing of requests.

1. Request sent to Controller
2. Work scheduled on background service (IHostedService)
3. Controller returns 202
4. Background service performs long running operation

As the application will be running on IIS, a pool recycle can happen after the controller has returned a response. I would like to implement a way to allow the application to do a graceful shutdown - finishing it's currently executing tasks, but not accepting any new.

I am having difficulties having the graceful shutdown run to end.
For testing purposes I've simplified the `StopAsync()` method, so now it only contains an async 20 second wait:

```
public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Hosted service is stopping...");

        try
        {
            // Signal cancellation to the executing method
            _stoppingTokenSource.Cancel();

            _logger.LogInformation("Delay by 20s");
            await Task.Delay(20000, cancellationToken);
            _logger.LogInformation("Delay over");
        }
        finally
        {
            // Await all pending download requests
            await Task.WhenAny(Task.WhenAll(_pendingTasks), Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, cancellationToken));

            _logger.LogInformation("Hosted service has been stopped successfully.");
        }
    }
```

The logs only show show:

- Hosted service is stopping...
- Delay by 20s

Looking at **EventViewer** I can see 2 events raised for the shutdown with exactly 10 seconds in between them:

- Sent shutdown HTTP message to process '11104' and received http status '202'.
- Failed to gracefully shutdown process '11104'.

**I have already tried:**

Settings up shutdown timeout on `Program.cs`

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseShutdownTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
```

Check Advanced Settings of application pool:

[image]

If you have done something similar, could you please let me know if I'm doing something wrong / point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

**EDIT**

While debugging the application, shutting down with CTRL + C produces the expected behaviour.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this issue?

Comment: @pcdev, I've found a solution although it requires the alteration of the web config file. I've posted it as answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found a solution after having another look at the issue again.

It seems like ASP.NET Core Module in IIS have a separate shutdown time limit, which can be configured in the `web.config` file as:

```xml
    <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
          <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <aspNetCore
            shutdownTimeLimit="30"    - set timeout here in seconds
            processPath="dotnet"
            arguments=".\GracefulShutdown.dll"
            stdoutLogEnabled="false"
            stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

Reference to settings at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Ideally this should be available through code, which is still something I'm trying to resolve. If you find a way to do it, please share in comment.

Comment: That's very useful information, thanks! We're trying to do exactly the same sort of thing as you've outlined, so this answer will come in handy.

Comment: Glad to hear. I think you should still keep the UseShutdownTimeout in the startup, as that will be the one triggering the cancellation of the token in the StopAsync method after the period has ended. Might worth setting it to be a bit shorter than the actual timeout of the ASP.NET Core Module, just to avoid race conditions.

Comment: Nice! Is there a way to move this option to `appsettings.json`?

Comment: @AsValeO not as far as I know.. I think ASP.NET Core Module is started prior to launching your application, so I don't think `appsettings.json` could alter the contents. If you find a way, please keep us updated!

Answer (score 2):

In Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostEnvironment env) function 
Register to ApplicationStopping in IHostApplicationLifetime ( Triggered when the application host is performing a graceful shutdown. Shutdown will block until this event completes)

```
  var applicationLifetime = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHostApplicationLifetime>();
  applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnShutdown);
```

private void OnShutdown()
{
  Write your code here that you want before shutdown, you can delay shutdown by Thread.Sleep();
}

Comment: What exactly is `app`?