# How do I (gracefully) shut down a worker service from within itself?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I'm using the .NET Core 3.1 worker service template to build a Windows Service.

I gather that the basic flow should be handled within `ExecuteAsync`, roughly like so:

```cs
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                try
                {
                    _Logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);

                    await SomeMethodThatDoesTheWork(stoppingToken);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _Logger.LogError(ex, "Global exception occurred. Will resume in a moment.");
                }

                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), stoppingToken);
            }
        }
```

I'm trying to properly signal from within the process that I want the app to shut down.

When stopping the service, I assume `StopAsync()` gets called. This seems to work fine. So I thought `await StopAsync()` would do the trick, but afterwards, `ExecuteAsync` still keeps running (so I'm guessing `StopAsync` won't request cancellation, and you're not supposed to call it yourself).

So I amended my loop with another bool:

```cs
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested && !_ShuttingDown)
```

This does exit the loop, and never enters `ExecuteAsync` again. However, the app just keeps on running. According to the debugger, it just stays on `host.Run()`.

How do I signal to the application host that I want to shut down?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows Service running Async code not waiting on work to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168992/windows-service-running-async-code-not-waiting-on-work-to-complete)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Graceful shutdown of IHostedService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51634638/graceful-shutdown-of-ihostedservice)

Comment: No. The first is the opposite problem (the service is apparently stuck waiting). The second is close, but this isn't an ASP.NET context. However, overriding `StopAsync` may be the required path, but doesn't seem like the correct design.

Comment: Can you provide some context, shut down a service from itself doesn't look a common need.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core, background services are independent from the application. It's possible, e.g., for services to finish and yet the application continues executing. If you want your application to exit when your background service finishes, then you'll need to wire that up yourself.

You can [inject `IHostApplicationLifetime` into your service and then call `IHostApplicationLifetime.StopApplication`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2020/06/backgroundservice-gotcha-application-lifetime.html). Something like this:

```
public sealed class MyService : BackgroundService
{
  private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _hostApplicationLifetime;
  private readonly ILogger<MyService> _logger;

  public MyService(IHostApplicationLifetime hostApplicationLifetime, ILogger<MyService> logger)
  {
    _hostApplicationLifetime = hostApplicationLifetime;
    _logger = logger;
  }

  protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
  {
    try
    {
      while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
      {
        try
        {
          _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
          await SomeMethodThatDoesTheWork(stoppingToken);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          _logger.LogError(ex, "Global exception occurred. Will resume in a moment.");
        }

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), stoppingToken);
      }
    }
    finally
    {
      _logger.LogCritical("Exiting application...");
      _hostApplicationLifetime.StopApplication();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "You can inject IHostApplicationLifetime into your service and then call IHostApplicationLifetime.StopApplication." Bingo, I think that's what I was looking for!

Comment: Would calling StopAsync() also work?

Comment: @JDawg: You mean on `IHost`? I believe that would wait for all background services to complete, including this one.

Comment: @StephenCleary While calling _hostApplicationLifetime.StopApplication(), successfully stops the app, I'm finding Dispose() methods for resources are not getting called. In my case, I have an async logger that is not finished writing its messages to disk. Whereas, if I CTRL+C the app running in the console, resources are properly cleaned, and my logger finishes writing all its messages. So while this gets the job done, I'm not sure it's the most correct approach.

Comment: @StephenCleary, disregard, my issue was resolved by -- https://andrewlock.net/four-ways-to-dispose-idisposables-in-asp-net-core/, e.g. my logger was registered improperly with the host for disposal. Forgive the false alarm-- situation normal.

Comment: @StephenCleary - I have the opposite issue. I have a BackgroundService which run continuously (it's a ticker plant that generates random price changes). I deploy it to an App Service. When I shut down my App Service, I want the ticker plant to stop sending prices. How do I do that?

Comment: @Quarkly: The `CancellationToken` passed to `ExecuteAsync` will be set when the host is shutdown.

Answer (score -5):

Services are not supposed to stop themselves, they are not applications - they are services...

Why do you want to stop the service from within the service? Perhaps you want a scheduled task instead of a service.

You could always use a ServiceController or similar class to send the stop event to the service

Comment: The original use case here is for self-update. The service gets a signal that a new version is available, and the existing version should gracefully shut down. I can also envision other use cases where an API would request a shut down, though.

Comment: You should probably use a secondary 'helper' or 'bootstrap' service to perform this. Imagine you push a botched update to the service, then it cannot update itself anymore

Comment: Right, but I would still want to allow the main process to shut down gracefully… surely there’s a nicer/less roundabout way than stopping the service?

Comment: Shouldn't this 'answer' be a comment instead of an answer?